# AddDays is not working in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi AddDays is not working in MVC4?

```
  public ActionResult customerid()
  {
    List<Customer> n = (from c in db.Customers where c.IsDeleted == false  select c).ToList();

        for (var i = 0; i < n.Count; i++)
        {
            var objCusCreatedDate=n[i].CreatedDate;

            var objNextDate = objCusCreatedDate.AddDays(+120);

         }
        return View();
    }
```

In this code i am getting error near to AddDays. please help me to solve this issue.

> Error  1   'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'AddDays' and no extension method 'AddDays' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is type of CreatedDate? it should be of type DateTime.

Comment: you shouldn't use `+` sign for positive value.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: the created date  type is DateTime Adil

Comment: Error 1 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'AddDays' and no extension method 'AddDays' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) F:\SnehaCRM\MAIN COPIES OF VISITORS FORM\18-02-2016\26-02-16\Sample Customer\Sample Customer\Controllers\ReportController.cs 174 53 SampleCustomer     This is the ERROR

Comment: If your property is nullable, then you need to convert it to a `DateTime` before using `AddDays` - e.g. `objCusCreatedDate.GetValueOrDefault().AddDays(120);`

Comment: Stephen  can you explain me this line objCusCreatedDate.GetValueOrDefault().AddDays(120);

Comment: [GetValueOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx) converts `DateTime?` to `DateTime` (if it has a value, the result will be the value, but if its `null`, the result will be `1/1/0001`

Answer (score 2):

Since your field `CreatedDate` is nullable, you need to use property `Value` to get the actual date:

```
var objCusCreatedDate=n[i].CreatedDate.Value;
var objNextDate = objCusCreatedDate.AddDays(120);
```

You can only do this if you know, that all dates will be populated with values. Otherwise you will get an exception.

Alternatively you can use method [`GetValueOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6d4f1d(v=vs.110).aspx) and specify the default value that you want to use if the date is null. In this example default value is set to `DateTime.Now`:

```
var objCusCreatedDate=n[i].CreatedDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now);
var objNextDate = objCusCreatedDate.AddDays(120);
```

Comment: Wrong way around - `var objCusCreatedDate=n[i].CreatedDate.Value;` (but should probably check if `null` (adding 120 days to a `null` date would not make sense)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for pointing this out, I updated the answer

Comment: I would probably enhance that with `if (objCusCreatedDate=n[i].CreatedDate.HasValue) { .... }`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(objCusCreatedDate.HasValue)
  var objNextDate = objCusCreatedDate.Value.AddDays(+120);
```